# I can't login after changing my Minecraft username

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I recently changed my Minecraft username. Since I could not login to the server, when I was logging in, I used my regular name. I use the password that I always use, but it doesn't work.

Comment: If you merged your Minecraft and Mojang account, you must use your Mojang email and password

Comment: If you are joining cracked server, where you have to /login, then we won't help you there. First, having such a server is illegal and second you need to contact server admin to deal with that. You should use only normal servers, then change of name won't make any diference....

Answer (score 3):

**If you mean the Minecraft Website:**
If you have a Mojang account, login with your e-mail instead of your username.

Try logging in with both usernames, old and new, making sure your password is correct if you are 100% sure you have a Minecraft account and NOT a Mojang one.

As a last resort, contact Mojang.

**If you mean /login in a server:**
Like Antoine said in the comments, servers with /login are cracked and you shouldn't use them anyway. However, your login password *should* be the same.